# Hyperbolic function equations. Where do they come from?

Tags: calculus

My text (Stewart's Early transcendentals) is going into hyperbolic functions, but I'm a bit confused about some statements they are making. All I know about hyperbolic functions is that the distances between a point on the hyperbola and the two foci are constant. IT's the locus of all these points I think. This text I find confusing:

[image]

1. On the circle... if the angle is $\frac{\pi}{6}$, the area is $\frac{\pi}{6}$ too right? The area isn't double? Say the radius is 1, that means the area is $\pi \cdot r^2 = \pi$ and we divide the area the area by 6 because of the radian measure. But why does the text say the trig case t represents twice the area of the shaded sector?
2. What does $\cosh{t}$ represent?
3. Why does $\sinh{x}$ equal $\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$?

Comment: For the exponential form, you can look at the Taylor series expansions of $\sinh$, $\cosh$, and $\exp$ around zero to see why that should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you mean on the circle of radius 1, if the angle is x and $$0 < x < 2\pi,$$ and you want the area between the line joining the origin to the circle with the angle x from the positive horizontal x axis (as in your diagram above), then actually the area is *not* x, but half of x. To see this, note the area of the whole circle is $$\pi r^2 = \pi*1 = \pi$$ The area of half the circle is then $$\frac{\pi}{2},$$ which occurs when $$x = \pi.$$ Thus, the angle *is* double the area, just as in the hyperbolic definition. You can show this is true in general by using the fact that the radius cuts the circle's circumference, which is *double* its area.

EDIT: I saw you commented the other answer about this, so here's a full explanation. At angle x, you're cutting off a proportion of the circle's circumference. In fact, if C is the circumference of the circle, you're cutting off precisely $$\frac{x}{2\pi}*C,$$ right? Because cutting off a circle's circumference cuts off the same proportion of the area (if you think about the line from the origin to the point), then replacing that C with the area, A, works. Test this out with x being pi or half pi and so in. In the case, where our circle has radius 1, then we have:
$$\frac{x}{2\pi}A = \frac{x}{2\pi}\pi = \frac{x}{2} $$
Thus our area is half the angle (or, our angle is double the area).

2. cosh(t) is the x co-ordinate of the point, and sin(t) is the y co-ordinate, just as with sin and cos, except the object whose points we're taking is a hyperbola instead of a circle.
3. See other answers

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\cosh t$ and $\sinh t$ represent the coordinates of the point P on the hyperbola such that the shaded area between the ray OP and the hyperbola is equal to $\frac{t}2$.

For this reason the fundamental relationship for hyperbolic functions is

$$x^2-y^2=1\implies \cosh^2 x -\sinh^2 x =1$$

From integral calculation it turns out that

$\cosh x=\frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$

$\sinh x=\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$

Note that also for the trigonometric circle for an angle $\theta$ the area is $\theta/2$, just note indeed that for $\theta=2\pi$ the area is $\pi$ (R=1).

Comment: could you answer my question about trig and the circle too? Is t really represent 2x the area of the shaded part of a circle?

Comment: Yes for the circle for an angle $\theta$ the area is $\theta/2$, just note that for $\theta=2\pi$ the area is $\pi$ (assuming R=1).